# Why Oracle would set a PCT_FREE value for MLOG$ when there will never be an update

Tags: oracle

Found PCTFREE on MLOG table value to 60 or  90 [or anything other than 0, really, since the entries in an MLOG table never get updated, only inserted and deleted]. Don’t know if these were delivered form Oracle this way. My question is why Oracle would set a PCT_FREE value for MLOG$ when there will never be an update. Can anyone please update me here.

Thanks in advance .

Thanks,SM

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption that "the entries in an MLOG table never get updated" might not be right. According to the MOS Doc ID 100498.1, Oracle will update the materialized view log table under certain circumstances:

> During the Refresh Phase, the MLOG$_XXX.SNAPTIME$$ column of all rows
>   in that are satisfied by the refresh query are updated with the
>   current refresh timestamp .
>
> Finally, the Wrap-up Phase does the following:
>
> a. Sets SLOG$.SNAPTIME to the current refresh time.
>
> b. Sets SNAP_REFTIME$.SNAPTIME to the current refresh time.
>
> c. Sets MLOG$.OLDEST_PK to current refresh time if current 
>   refresh time < MIN (SLOG$.SNAPTIME).
>
> d. Deletes all rows from MLOG$_XXX where SNAPTIME$$ < current refresh time.

From the above explanation is clear that the MLOG$ tables can be subject of various kind of updates.